# Custom dialog in launcher activity overwriting activity layout

Tags: java, android, layout, dialog, onclicklistener

I have a dialog in my launcher activity that requires some user input and to display it I have this code in onCreate()...

```
 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
 DialogBinding dialogBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.dialog);
 popupBinding.dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           dialog.dismiss();
       }
   });
 dialog.show();
```

The dialog button has an onClick listener to close it, but in order to do that, the dialog must be declared final. Previously (when this activity was not the launcher), I had the dialog declared as an instance variable, but this causes an error now.

```
private Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
```

However, declaring the dialog in the onCreate method causes the launcher activity's layout to be replaced with the dialog's so that the dialog appears over a copy of itself.

[image: Launcher Activity with dialog]

I'm not sure why it is doing that, but I was wondering if there is a way to prevent this. Thanks!

Comment: What's popupBinding? Do you need databinding for your activity only or also for the dialog?
I've posted an aswer, I can make it more concrete if you post the whole Activity code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This accidentily sets the dialog layout as the content view for your activity.

```
DialogBinding dialogBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.dialog);
```

So you're mixing your activity with the dialog.

For your Activity, this should be something like

```
MyActivityBinding activityBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.my_activity);
```